# change colors to black in existing ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a question about the `ggplot2` package (author: Hadley Wickham). I have **existing ggplot objects** with distinct colors (resp shapes, linetype, fill...) that I would like to map to a single color, e.g. black. What is the recommended approach?

**Clarification: I have to work with these ggplot objects: I cannot re-make them**

A ggplot with variables grouped as factors: **this is the plot object p I need to work with**

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, group = factor(cyl), colour = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Several approaches I know of:

#### 1. `scale_colour_grey` hack

```
p + scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = 0) + # gives correct, useless legend
    guides(color = FALSE)
```

The shorter `p + scale_colour_grey(0,0)` does not work, you have to be explicit about `start` and `end`.

#### 2. `scale_colour_manual` with `rep()` hack

```
p + scale_colour_manual(values = rep("black",3)) # gives correct, useless legend
```

The simpler `scale_colour_manual(values = "black")` does not work. This was probably the most intuitive approach. Having to specify the length of the vector makes it less attractive an approach.

#### 3. `geom_point()` recalled

```
p + geom_point(colour = "black") + # gives incorrect legend
    guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

It is well documented that the following is not allowed:

```
 p + scale_colour_manual(colour = "black")
Error in discrete_scale(aesthetic, "manual", pal, ...) : 
  unused argument (colour = "black")
```

Comment: If you want black points, then remove `colour=factor(cyl)`. You don't need `group=factor(cyl)` either. Black is the default color, so you don't need to set it. However, if you decided you wanted all the points to be, say, red, you would do `color="red"` *outside* of `aes`.

Comment: If you want gray scale plots or similar, take a look at `?help(theme_grey)`

Comment: @eipi10, I have clarified that I have these plots, I cannot remake them, so I cannot change the bit that says ``group=factor(cyl)`` I have to act after it. Please consider un-downvoting. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @lmo, Thanks, if you have code to change the colors to black, please post an answer.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks, so please consider upvoting. :-)

Comment: @PatrickT Just a clarification , when you say you have these charts do you mean ggplot objects or image files of these charts?

Comment: Assuming you have the plot object, you can do `p + scale_colour_manual(values=rep("black",length(unique(mtcars$cyl))))` that will map every level of `cyl` to black in your example.

Comment: @GauravTaneja, I mean ggplot objects. I produce large amounts of them in colors, but then I also want to output a version without the colors. As you can see, I know how to do that. I'm interested in knowing the recommended approach, if there is one. My methods are all a bit 'hacky'.

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @PatrickT In that case you can use `ggplot_build` to extract the data and change the `color` column to `black`

Comment: @GauravTaneja, thanks, good idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the color mapping directly seems to work:

```
p_bw = p
p_bw$mapping$colour = NULL
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p, p_bw)
```

[image]

Comment: I like that, thanks! I was able to ``ggsave`` the ``p_bw`` object and print it on screen as usual. And it removes the legend, so whether this is the recommended approach or not, I don't care: it's very clear and short: I like it! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you're happy. You might want to hold off accepting for a bit - I'm not at all sure how well this would work with, e.g., multiple layers, layers using different data sets / mappings. I'm curious to see what other answers come along.

Comment: okay I will keep it open a little while longer. I was anxious to close it to prevent more downvoting from hasty readers of the question 8-|

Comment: I think all the downvotes came before you clarified your question. I think making clear in the title that the plots already exist will help a lot.

Comment: thanks, you're right I did not pay enough attention to that. I'll try to clarify the title too. +1

Comment: an afterthought: I wonder if the ``override.aes()`` function is intended for this sort of situation?

Comment: `override.aes()` is used in legends. For example, because of overplotting you might set `alpha = 0.1`, but you want full opacity in a color legend, so you use `override.aes` in the `guide_legend()` call.

Comment: I have just discovered ``update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "black"))``, but it will work only if I have **NOT** set a group or a colour inside the ``aes()``, so not, it appears, the adequate tool either.

Comment: Correct, as the name suggests `update_geom_defaults` is for updating defaults, not overriding things that have been set.

Comment: I don't think looking further will find a built-in idiomatic way for doing this. *Not* being able to edit the original plotting code puts you well outside the standard ggplot workflow, which means there aren't standard "accepted" ways to do those things.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to set the points to black and get rid of the color legend, I think you can just to this:

```
p + scale_colour_manual(values=rep("black",length(unique(mtcars$cyl))),
                        guide=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks eipi10, but this is already one of the solutions I present (except I wrote ``rep("black", 3)``  for clarity.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why this isn't acceptable to you. It sets the points to black and removes the color legend, but doesn't require going outside the "standard" ggplot workflow.